# Finding the Java class for a given Realm schema

Tags: java, realm

On a `Realm` object, I call `getSchema().getAll()` to obtain the available schemas, and then `getClassName()` on a schema to get its name.

How can I subsequently read that schema's data, i.e. the query the Java objects it holds? I have tried calling `where(<class>).findAll()` on the `Realm` object, but `where()` expects an argument whose type is the Java class in question, and I have not found a way to determine that class given only the schema name. Note that `RealmObjectSchema.getClassName` returns an unqualified name that doesn't fit this purpose.

So basically the question is how to find the Java class that corresponds to a schema. The information is there, as I can see from the `classToTable` and `classToSchema` fields in `RealmSchema`.

Or maybe `where().findAll()` isn't the best approach to retrieve the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well a possibility would be to rely on some package internal API, the RealmProxyMediator to obtain the classes:

```
RealmProxyMediator mediator = realm.configuration.getSchemaMediator();
final Set<Class<? extends RealmModel>> modelClasses = mediator.getModelClasses();
```

But according to the Realm 0.88.0 change log:

> Removed `RealmConfiguration.getSchemaMediator()` from public API which was deprecated in 0.86.0. Please use `RealmConfiguration.getRealmObjectClasses()` to obtain the set of model classes (#1797).

So just use [`RealmConfiguration.getRealmObjectClasses()`](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmConfiguration.html#getRealmObjectClasses--).

> `getRealmObjectClasses()`
>
> `public Set<Class<? extends RealmModel>> getRealmObjectClasses()`:
>
> Returns the unmodifiable Set of model classes that make up the schema for this Realm.

Then you can just iterate that and use the `class`es returned in the set for your `where(class)` parameter.

Comment: Thanks. There's still a snag - I would like to pass the class to RealmSchema.getSchemaForClass() to check if that's the schema I'm looking for, but it turns out that method is package-local. So it seems the best I can do is iterate the schemas and compare their names to the simple (unqualified) class names. Not perfect, but good enough for now.

Comment: Just make sure you don't obfuscate the RealmObjects when you use Proguard.

Comment: I always tend to add `-keepnames public class * extends io.realm.RealmObject` just to make sure :D

Answer (score 0):

that might be to late but adding as I've ended up here with I believe same problem and what I did (without disabling obfuscation) to go through all models in realm (for some logging purposes) is

```
realm.configuration.realmObjectClasses.forEach {
                    val realmClassName = realm.where(it).typeQueried
                    val numberOfRecords = realm.where(it).count()

                }
```

thanks to that I was able to obtain original class names (or at least some readable version as I use `RealmNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES` ) and still have obfuscation in place